# Predicting Antennae Coverage using SPLAT

Tags: machine-learning, python, data, data-science-model

I have been trying to predict the network coverage based on antennae characteristics (such as height, lat and long etc).
Came across this package which seems to be dormant now (https://github.com/NZRS/wavetrace)

This is the error message that i get-

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/70/qd0s3l2d6fnf4jk2n2w0fryw0000gp/T/ipykernel_96803/1928621339.py in <module>
     22 out_path = TMP_DIR+'/splat_files'
     23 wt.process_topography(topography_path, out_path, 
---> 24   high_definition=high_definition)
     25 
     26 #%ll -h {out_path}

~/PycharmProjects/Netowrth/wavetrace/wavetrace/main.py in process_topography(in_path, out_path, high_definition)
    418         # Convert to SDF
    419         cp = subprocess.run([splat, f.name], cwd=str(f.parent),
--> 420           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, check=True)
    421 
    422         # Get name of output file, which SPLAT! created and which differs

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Netowrth/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    486         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
    487 
--> 488     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    489         try:
    490             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Netowrth/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    798                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:
    802             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Netowrth/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1549                         if errno_num == errno.ENOENT:
   1550                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1553 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'srtm2sdf': 'srtm2sdf'
```

This is the code that i am using here-

```
out_path = TMP_DIR+'/splat_files'
wt.process_topography(topography_path, out_path, 
  high_definition=high_definition)
```

Please note that this python notebook can also be found here if you want to look at the entire [workflow](https://github.com/NZRS/wavetrace/blob/master/ipynb/examples.ipynb)

According to the module, this is the definition of process_topography

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import json
import csv
import re
import math

from shapely.geometry import Point
import requests

def process_topography(in_path, out_path, high_definition=False):
    """
    Convert each SRTM HGT topography file in the directory ``in_path`` to a SPLAT! Data File (SDF) file in the directory ``out_path``,     creating the directory if it does not exist.
    If ``high_definition``, then assume the input data is high definition.

    INPUT:
        - ``in_path``: string or Path object specifying a directory
        - ``out_path``: string or Path object specifying a directory
        - ``high_definition``: boolean

    OUTPUT:
        None.

    NOTES:
        - Calls SPLAT!'s ``srtm2sdf`` or ``srtm2sdf-hd`` 
          (if ``high_definition``) command to do the work
        - Raises a ``subprocess.CalledProcessError`` if SPLAT! fails to 
          convert a file
        - Each SRTM1 or SRTM3 file must have a name of the form <SRTM tile ID>[.something].hgt.zip or <SRTM tile ID>[.something].hgt, e.g. S36E173.SRTMGL3.hgt.zip 
    """
    in_path = Path(in_path)
    out_path = Path(out_path)
    if not out_path.exists():
        out_path.mkdir(parents=True)

    splat = 'srtm2sdf'
    if high_definition:
        splat += '-hd'

    sdf_pattern = re.compile(r"[\d\w\-\:]+\.sdf")

    for f in in_path.iterdir():
        if not (f.name.endswith('.hgt') or f.name.endswith('.hgt.zip')):
            continue

        # Unzip if necessary
        is_zip = False
        if f.name.endswith('.zip'):
            is_zip = True
            shutil.unpack_archive(str(f), str(f.parent))
            tile_id = f.name.split('.')[0]
            f = f.parent/'{!s}.hgt'.format(tile_id)

        # Convert to SDF
        cp = subprocess.run([splat, f.name], cwd=str(f.parent),
          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, check=True)

        # Get name of output file, which SPLAT! created and which differs
        # from the original name, and move the output to the out path
        m = sdf_pattern.search(cp.stdout)
        name = m.group(0)        
        src = in_path/name
        tgt = out_path/name
        shutil.move(str(src), str(tgt))

        # Clean up
        if is_zip:
            f.unlink()
```

Any help is appreciated. From the error, it seemed like srtmsdf must be a folder but according to the python subprocess, it has to be a function

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the function tries to call the SPLAT! command line using `srtm2sdf` on all files in `in_path`. Trying to run a command line program using `subprocess.run` when the command line program doesn't exist (i.e. returns a 'command not found' error when trying to run a command on the command line) gives a `FileNotFoundError` instead of the actual error you get from the command line. Based on this it seems you haven't installed SPLAT!, which is part of [the requirements of this package](https://github.com/NZRS/wavetrace#installation). Therefore make sure you have installed all prerequisites needed for this package to work (SPLAT!, GDAL, and ImageMagick).

Comment: Great insight! Let me install and get back to you

Comment: I still get the same error even after installing splat, from the error it seems that python has assumed that 'srtm2sdf' is a folder. (hence, file/folder not found). I even tried creating a folder by that name but that gave me a 'permission denied error'

Comment: What do you get when you try to run `srtm2sdf` from you command line?

Comment: says " command not found: srtm2sdf" . which could mean problems with splat since i installed splat 0.32

Comment: So SPLAT! is not yet installed correctly, the repository says you have to use version 1.4.0 or above, so make sure that the version you install is high enough.

Comment: Still gives me the same error even after installing with correct splat version